# Is it possible to set up rules in Mail that do not appear in the rules list?

Tags: macos, mail.app, mail-rules

I'd like to set up a few rules in Mail.app but not have them appear in the list of rules in Mail's preferences. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know of. However, depending on your email provider, you may be able to set up server-side rules, which wouldn't appear in Mail.app and would be applied before your Mail.app rules.